Unable to Turn On TCL TV Using HDMI-CEC with Raspberry Pi 5
OS: Raspberry Pi OS (64-bit)
I have a Google TCL TV connected to a Raspberry Pi 5, and I am trying to control the TV using HDMI-CEC. I have enabled HDMI-CEC in the TV settings.
I am able to turn off the TV with the following command:
echo 'standby 0' | cec-client -s -d 1

However, when I try to turn on the TV with the following command, it does not work:
echo 'on 0' | cec-client -s -d 1


what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

I used to have a TCL tv, it's CEC implementation was rubbish - how old is the TV?

I second @JaromandaX's question. I have old LG TV. The LG CEC is so bad, I installed CEC blockers on all inputs.
